# Close open info window on individual markers 'react-google-maps'

Tags: google-maps, reactjs

I am using React-Google-Maps. I am trying to get my infowindow to open and close on each click of the marker. I set a showInfo key on my object when I mapped over my data and call a function to change the value of the boolean on click. This does not seem to work when trying to display my infowindow. Any suggestions? Code here.

render() {
    const markers = this.props.markers.map((item, i) => {

```
  const marker = {
    position: {
      lat: item.position.lat,
      lng: item.position.lon
    },
      title: item.title,
      showInfo: false,
      price: `${item.price}/day`,
      images: `http://res.cloudinary.com/letitmow/image/upload/w_40,h_40/${item.images[0]}.jpg`,
  }
  return <Marker
  onClick={()=> {marker.showInfo = !marker.showInfo}}
  {...marker}>
 {marker.showInfo && (
  <InfoWindow
   onCloseClick={()=>{marker.showInfo = !marker.showInfo}}
   >
    <Link to={`/listings/${item._id}`}>
      <div>
        <h2>{marker.title}</h2>
        <img src={marker.images} />
        <h3>{marker.price}</h3>
      </div>

    </Link>

  </InfoWindow>
)}
  </Marker>
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to run some logic when the marker is clicked. Right now whenever the marker is clicked, marker.showInfo 
is set to false and the corresponding InfoWindow is not rendering.

Instead, maybe try creating a function that is called when the marker is clicked.
You could call it something similar to "handleMarkerTap"

Some quick code to provide you with the idea below:

change your onClicks:

```
onClick={() => handleMarkerTap(currentMarker)}
onCloseClick={() => handleMarkerTap(currentMarker)}
```

Create a function that receives a marker object and toggles the showInfo property.

```
handleMarkerTap(marker) {

  if (marker.showInfo === false) {
    marker.showInfo = true
  } else if (marker.showInfo === true) {
    marker.showInfo = false
  }
}
```

Now, when the marker is clicked, the showInfo property of that marker should be set to true and your InfoWindow should render.

I hope this helps!